# Revmob in ios application - How to tell if user installed app

Tags: android, iphone, ios, revmob

I am converting my app to use RevMob.

I would like to implement code that informs me if the user actually installs the app that was advertised by Revmob?

Can someone point me in the right direction.. I don't see anything in the SDK documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far they don't expose any API that can inform you that, you can check on their [iOS](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/index.html) and [Android](http://sdk.revmob.com/android-api/index.html) sites.

The delegate method installDidReceived is used when the SDK notify that your app was installed, not the advertised one.

Any other Ad Network offer support to this?

Comment: I see a lot of games that offer up in game 'currency' when a user installs the advertised app.  How do they go about confirming this?  Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the advertised app notify a server about the install and   this server credit the 'currency' for the user. Later the app that has the add ask for the server to the users 'currency'. So it's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: confirmed with revmob.. you are correct.  Not possible in the current SDK.  Thanks.